# Netflix app System Configuration error

Tags: windows-8, netflix

When I try to watch a movie or TV show on Netflix, this is the error I get, after it is done loading:

[image]

> System Configuration Problem
>
> An unexpected error occurred when trying to play video. This may be caused by an out-of-date audio driver. Try updating your audio driver or disable Dolby Digital Plus.
>
> If you need assistance with this problem, please call (...)
>
> Error code: **W8156-8000FFFF**

I reinstalled my sound drivers, but Windows 8 didn’t find anything that fixed the problem.

Has anyone else had this problem and managed to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing this registry (`Win` + `R`: type in `regedit` to get to the registry editor) and rebooting?

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Audio]
>   "DisableProtectedAudioDG"=dword:00000001

If it is already set to 1, try setting it to 0.

This forces the audio engine to run in a regular process instead of a protected one. It may cause issues with any DRM content though.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/mediafoundationdevelopment/thread/b16a608b-18e3-44aa-af5c-6be678e4db98) [Secondary source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/netflix-app-error-w8156-8000ffff/e61222af-59b0-41f9-b30e-e203d1980d58#LastReply)

Comment: Netflix content is DRM content. Sounds like the author disabled this feature ( i.e. already did your suggestion ) and needs to re-enable it.

Comment: @Ramhound Nope, didn‘t touch a thing. It was like this just after I had upgraded from Windows 7 and downloaded the app—and has stayed this way since. I don‘t like messing with the registry, when I can avoid it.